# Page management: How to add space in Detail band

Tags: jasper-reports

I have created a report with *iReport*. And I am having problem with **Detail** band.

I want specific number of records for a page, even if the records with data or with out 
data.

Actually I have only one record in my **Detail** band, I am getting report like this:

```
---------------- Here Detail band started
Empid | Empname
124   | medopal
---------------- Here Detail band ended
```

But my requirement is like below:

```
---------------- Here Detail band started
Empid | Empname
124   | medopal
      |
      |
      |
      |
      |
      |
      |
      |
---------------Here Detail band ended
```

To print the **Detail** band even there is no records to make occupy entire page.

Comment: This is almost totally incomprehensible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the element "Page Break" in iReport with a conditional "Print When Expression".

The expression could be something like  `$F{REPORT_COUNT}%20==0`

Comment: hai medophal,
thanks for your timely reply,
actually i am not getting the exact requirement
my problem is 
see the fallowing
actually i have only one record in my detail bond,i am getting reportlike this

----------------here detail bond started
Empid | Empname
124   | medopal
----------------here detail bond ended

But my reQuirement is like bilow

----------------here detail bond started
Empid | Empname
124   | medopal
      |
      |
      |
      |
      |
      |
      |
      |
---------------here detail bond ended
to ptint the detail even there is no records to make occupy 
entaire page