# Adding gap in Detail band

Tags: jasper-reports

I have created one purchase order report with *iReport*.

In my report i am having only one record its coming like this

```
==================group header
pro_id|productname
==================detail bond started
120   | bag
================== detail bond ended
```

But I want the design like this

```
==================group header
pro_id|productname
==================detail bond started
120   | bag
      |
      |
      |                  I WANT THIS GAP IN DETAIL BAND WITH OUT RECORDS
      |
      |
      |
      |
      |
================== detail bond ended
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: Edited you question. You dont have to SHOUT.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Page management: How to add space in Detail band](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176867/page-management-how-to-add-space-in-detail-band)

Answer (score 1):

Surround your detail band with an empty band, lets say `gapBand`, the header will be 0 height, and the footer will be as much as the gap height you want

Answer (score 0):

Make this gap in the beginning of the *next* band.